# Yii-framework UrlManager performance

Tags: performance, yii, url-routing

I have Route table with route rules ((1000+)) to load into UrlManager while init.
But the bottleneck is foreach cycle, which is too slow.

Possible answers: NoSQL database, memcache? Could you advice something?

```
    $oldRules = $this->rules;
    $this->rules = array();
    $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM route');
    $routes = Route::model()->cache(Yii::app()->params['cache_expire_time'], $dependency)->findAll();

    Yii::app()->cache->set('routes', $routes, Yii::app()->params['cache_expire_time'], $dependency);

    // @todo Bottle neck on 1000+ rows (~1.3s on 1000 rows)
    foreach ($routes as $route) {
        $rule = array($route->routeable_controller . '/' . $route->routeable_action);
        if ($route->routeable_id) {
            $rule['defaultParams'] = array('id' => $route->routeable_id);
        }
        $this->rules[$route->pattern] = $rule;
    }

    $this->rules += $oldRules;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you jocks? have you read Yii definitive guide. They have clearly mentioned that while parsing a request each rule in urlManager rules is applied to the request URL till the matching rule is found. Loading of all rules in memcache is not going to work.
Again these rules are matched with the help of regular expressions which is an expensive code in itself.
I would say try to rewrite your rules so that single rule matches with multiple urls. try to move some of them in .htaccess (for missing actions or redirects)

Comment: Thank you for your opinion.
In db there are 1000+ of real estate objects (REO) and for each REO is stored unique uri in `route` table.

Comment: For example:
http://www.site.com/any_user_given_uri.html is mapped to apartment/view/id/1

http://www.site.com/any_user_given_uri1.html is mapped to apartment/view/id/2

http://www.site.com/any_user_given_uri2.html is mapped to apartment/list

I want user could set uri for any REO by himself.

Comment: I have around 10k REOs in my db. but URL rules are just 7. Thats not the point. you can write a single rule for the first 2 URLs listed. as `'/<term>.html'=>'apartment/view/'` now in admin view action get the `$term` from `$_GET['term']` and get your id from `$term`.   Secondly allowing a user to create URI is a good idea, but you should always try to add some constraints like in case of third uri you will not allow a user to use words `any_user_given_uri` in the uri as it is used to point to REO or REO id. I would suggest to go through special topics URL management in Yii definitive guide.

Comment: May be I should add `seo_url` field to each object in apartment table?

Comment: In UrlManager rules something like:

apartment/<seo_url:\w+> => apartment/view